# Can't find Azure Bot. Is it deprecated?

Tags: azure, sdk, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to create an Azure Bot via the bot framework SDK. I am following the documentation here,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned

The above documentation talks about provisioning a service called Azure Bot. But when I go to Azure and search for Azure Bot, there is no such item offered instead something call "Bot Services" is there. If I click on that and try to create a new bot service all I get in next screen a bunch of 3rd party(non-Azure) bots to use.

So just wondering, if anything called "Azure Bot" available in Azure?
May be the documentation above is old? If so anyone has links to new doc about how to use Bot Framework SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Azure bot service is not deprecated. Follow the procedure to get the bot service.

**Procedure**

1. Goto Azure portal

[Microsoft Azure](https://ms.portal.azure.com/)

2. Goto Resources

[image]

3. Search for **Azure Bot**

[image]

4. Click on **Create**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the procedure to **create Azure Bot.**

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying the blue search box in portal looking for a service called Azure Bot. But now that you showed, going to Create Resource option in dashboard, I was able to create it. Great!